# the https about my nodejs rest api

Tags: node.js, express, https

my rest api server is support for iOS app , now i must change it to https ,then i config the https with my domain's .pfx, when i restart my webservice, the ip address it works, but the domain show me nothing.

here is my code about https:

```
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');

var options = {
    pfx:fs.readFileSync('./keys/server.pfx'),
    passphrase:'your password'
};

https.createServer(options,function(req,res){
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end('hello world\n');
}).listen(3000,'127.0.0.1');
```

can anyone help me about this ?! thanks very much!!!

Comment: This sounds like either a DNS configuration issue or a routing problem getting from the internet to your public IP to your server.  How is your DNS configured?  To what IP address is the DNS name attached?

Comment: And, is there a reason your server is listening for 127.0.0.1, not your actual IP address?

Comment: what i need is listening my actual ip address ?